# Stay at the same position on page after closing Magnific Popup

Tags: magnific-popup

When I close the Magnific Popup, the page should be at the same position as when I opened the Magnific Popup. Right now, after closing Magnific Popup I have to scroll to the gallery that was opened.

Here is the website:
https://www.perfora.sk/produkty/dizajnove-plechy/

The problem is:

- always on Firefox (54.0.1 (32-bit))
- after refresh on Chrome (60.0.3112.101); if I open it second time, it
  works fine

Galleries with names: Rythmic Illusion Cubrik, Rythmic Orchestra, Rythmic Gota, Rythmic Exau and Rythmic Corail.

I have to say, that I have to scroll about 100px back to the gallery that was opened. It is not a lot, but I should stay at the same position after closing the Magnific Popup.

Thank you for your help.

[Described issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmhLx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try autoFocusLast:

```
autoFocusLast: false
```

To prevent last focused link/image after popup close. Option available since 2015/12/16.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the 'fixedContentPos' to false like so:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: '#popup-exit-form' //ID of inline element
  },
  fixedContentPos: false,
  type: 'inline',
  removalDelay: 500, //Delaying the removal in order to fit in the animation of the popup
  mainClass: 'mfp-fade mfp-fade-side', //The actual animation
});
```